# Why should exponential back-off(in GCM) wait twice the previous amount of time before retrying?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have read the GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) guide. It is written that on failure of registration client to GCM, we should retry the registration process. Google advices about exponential back-off: "the client app should wait twice the previous amount of time before retrying".

Why should the client app wait twice the previous amount of time before retrying?

Let's think this scenario;

1. My client downloaded the app.
2. Client didn't open the app until the night.
3. Client intended to open the app before sleep.
4. The app was started and the client used the offline features.
5. Client didn't have internet connection in this time.
6. So, my app would try to register the client to GCM all night until the client would have internet, exponential back-off time reached some hours or days.

So, isn't it a bad practice? Why does google advice this? I think, developer should set a maximum(limit) time to exponential back-off time, at least.

GCM Guide:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration

Comment: It is not meant to be used that way. Just try a few times with exponential backup and if after some time you are unable to register, give up and try next time they fire up the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As par link you gave, I found below sub link.

[ExponentialBackOff](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/ExponentialBackOff)

Please read it to understand the process better.

You try certain times(or till reaches max interval between two requests), and it needs to stop there. Then it will be in cycle again when user uses the app or you gets Internet_state_change event.

**[Example from the link :-](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/ExponentialBackOff)**

The default retry_interval is .5 seconds, default randomization_factor is 0.5, default multiplier is 1.5 and the default max_interval is 1 minute. For 10 tries the sequence will be (values in seconds) and assuming we go over the max_elapsed_time on the 10th try:

[image]

Comment: Links are broken :(